# Ui button doesn't move correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code for a crafting system that checks if the inventory has the ingredients needed to craft an item and adds a button to craft it. The problem is when I want to position my button it goes way off the canvas. I have seen some people saying that it has something to do with rect transform. I've been stuck with it for over an hour. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried
removing the setparent() function,
using anchoredPosition,
using localPosition

My code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Crafting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<recipe> recipes = new List<recipe>();
    public GameObject base_item, parent;
    List<GameObject> items = new List<GameObject>();
    public int y = 75;
    public int x = -45;
    public Inv inv;

    private void Start()
    {
        inv = GetComponent<Inv>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            checkitems();
            Debug.Log("y = " + y + " x = " + (x - 40));
        }
    }
    public void checkitems()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < recipes.Count; i++)
        {
            recipe r = recipes[i];
            for (int x = 0; x < r.ingredients.Count; x++)
            {
                if (!inv.hasitem(r.ingredients[x])){
                    return;
                }
            }
            showitem(r.result);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(int _slot)
    {
        recipe r = recipes[_slot];
        for (int i = 0; i < r.ingredients.Count; i++)
        {
            inv.removeitem(inv.getitem(r.ingredients[i]));
        }
        inv.additem(inv.getFirstAvailable(), r.result, r.stack);
    }

    public void showitem(string name)
    {
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(base_item);
        if (items.Count != 0)
        {
            if (((items.Count) % 3) != 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("first thing");
                obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector2(x, y);
                obj.transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
                obj.SetActive(true);
                items.Add(obj);
                x = x + 40;
                Debug.Log("x + 40");
            }
            else if (((items.Count + 1) % 3) == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("second thing");
                x = -45;
                Debug.Log("x + 40");
                y = y + 40;
                Debug.Log(" y + 40");
                obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector2(x, y);
                obj.transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
                obj.SetActive(true);
                items.Add(obj);
            }
        }else
        {
            obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector2(x, y);
            obj.transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
            obj.SetActive(true);
            items.Add(obj);
            x = x + 40;
            Debug.Log("x + 40");
        }
    }
}
```

Blue circle where it spawns. Red circle where I want it to be

[image: Image of the ui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are confusing a bunch of terms for being the issue of your problem. Firstly I want to address the red X over your scroll bar. Whenever this occurs, it means that your `RectTransform` of this UI object has been dragged from its positive vertices to negative or vice versa, causing it to almost invert. I would correct this but it is not the reason your objects are not childing correctly.

Generally, with UI objects, I would never use `LocalPosition`, just `AnchoredPosition`. `LocalPosition` is a field from `Transform` which I believe `RectTransform` inherits from. As `RectTransforms` have a lot of modifications to their position from `pivots`, `anchors`, and `anchored positions`, the `LocalPosition` will most likely need to recalculate data to properly move the object, whereas `AnchoredPosition` has already done these calculations.

I believe the issue with your current code is how you are using `SetParent`. There is a second parameter of [`SetParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) which governs whether the object keeps the same position based in world space after being childed. As you are not passing in a new `bool` for this parameter, it is defaulting to `true`. As you want your objects to be childed to the parent but not keep their world space positions, you would want to pass in `false`.

In your case, as it looks as if you want to set objects in a grid-like pattern childed to this `ScrollRect`,  I would attach a [`GridLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html) to the `Content` of your scroll and child the new objects to this object. You can set the max columns of this grid and spacing to give the same layout you are attempting to achieve in code.

To summarize, I would remove all the hand placement you are doing in code with `LocalPosition` and `AnchorPosition` and just attach a `GridLayoutGroup`. To fix the current positioning of your objects relative to the parent, change all lines of `obj.transform.SetParent(parent.transform);` to `obj.transform.SetParent(parent.transform, false);`. If you want to keep changing position locally in code instead of a layout element, use `SetParent` first, and use `AnchoredPosition` instead of `LocalPosition` as the `SetParent` with `false` passed in will override the position you set.